# how to copy one list to another list in flutter

Tags: list, flutter

I want to copy user inputs to list1 to another list say list2 and save it, then if user inputs something again that should be inserted in list1 and then again its content should be copied to list2.

**Output:**
let say user inputs A,B,C then it should be stored in list1.
list1=['A','B','C']
and list2 will be list2=['A','B','C']

then if again user inputs something let's say D,E,F then list1 will be
list1=['D','E','F']
and list2 will be list2=['A','B','C','D','E','F']

and i want that list2 contents on gridview

Here is what i have done:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

class Result extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function resetHandler;
  final int resultScore;
  List textList = [];
  Result(this.resultScore, this.textList, this.resetHandler);

  @override
  _ResultState createState() => _ResultState();
}

class _ResultState extends State<Result> {
  List textListCopy;
  var resultList;
  int index = 0;

  String get resultPhrase {
    if (widget.resultScore <= 8) {
      return 'You are awesome and innocent!';
    } else if (widget.resultScore <= 12) {
      return 'Pretty likeable!';
    } else if (widget.resultScore <= 16) {
      return 'You are .... Strange?!';
    } else {
      return 'You are so Bad!';
    }
  }

  Color colorSelect() {
    Color color;
    if (widget.textList[0] == 'Blue' &&
        widget.textList[1] == 'Rabbit' &&
        widget.textList[2] == 'A') {
      color = Colors.blue;
    } else if (widget.textList[0] == 'Blue' &&
        widget.textList[1] == 'Snake' &&
        widget.textList[2] == 'B') {
      color = Colors.green;
    } else if (widget.textList[1] == 'Lion') {
      color = Colors.orange;
    } else if (widget.textList[2] == 'C') {
      color = Colors.yellow;
    } else {
      color = Colors.white;
    }
    return color;
  }


  String indexSelection() {
   
    list2.addAll(widget.list1); //i am copying my list1 to list2 here

    print(list2);
    return list2[0];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    /*24 is for notification bar on Android*/
    final double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight - 24) / 2;
    final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;

    return Scaffold(
        body: //Center(
            //child:
            //Column(
            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            //children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: colorSelect()),
                child: //Center(
                    //child:
                    Column(children: [
                  Text(
                    resultPhrase,
                    //'Hello!!',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: widget.resetHandler,
                      child: Text(
                        'Restart Quiz',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )),
                  Expanded(
                      child: GridView.count(
                    childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
                    controller: new ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: false),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 0),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    children: [
                      Card(
                        child: Text(
                          indexSelection(),

                          //index += 1;
                          //textList[index],
                          //index += 1;
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      
                    ],
                  ))
                ])) //)
        //]) //)
        );
  }
}
```

Another file

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

        // Hide the debug banner
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('My First App'),
            ),
            body: _questionIndex < _questions.length
                ? Quiz(
                    answerQuestion: _answerQuestion,
                    questionIndex: _questionIndex,
                    questions: _questions,
                  )
                : Result(_total_score, textList, _resetQuiz))); //here i'm calling _resetQuiz function

  void _resetQuiz() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = 0;
      _total_score = 0;
      list1= []; //here i'm emptying my list1 everytime when RESET QUIZ button is pressed so that the final screen color changes in the basis of my answer selection
    });
```

**Update:**

i have tried from.list too, but every when user input something it only display that input, its not storing previous input

```
String indexSelection() {
    print(list1);
    list2= List.from(list1);
    print(list2);
    return list2[0];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```dart
list2.addAll(list1);
```

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-combine-lists-in-dart/)'s a good article about other ways to achieve the same.

Comment: Okay, good to know. I think your problem is more about state management in a flutter app than about list concatenation. I suggest to do some [introductory reading](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) and try out the respective sample apps to familiarize yourself with flutter app state in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```dart
List list2 = [...list1];
```

Comment: can you please edit my code where can i use it?

Comment: this is just another notation for assignment, I think @Hira wants concatenation though.

Comment: yes i want to concatenate list1 to list2. in other words i want previous items of list1 in list2 along with the current items of list1.